# Why my case statement throws error , incorrect syntax near '='?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

why my case statement throws this error:

***Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '='.***

Code:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Chart_SelectSmsComplaintsValidity]

 @FromDate datetime,
 @ToDate datetime

AS
BEGIN

    Select COUNT(ReceivedMessages.ID) As ReceivedMessageID, 
    CASE ReceivedMessages.IsComplaint WHEN ReceivedMessages.IsComplaint=0 
    THEN 'Incomplete'
    WHEN ReceivedMessages.IsComplaint=1 THEN 'Complete'
    WHEN ReceivedMessages.IsComplaint=-3 THEN 'Inappropriate' END from ReceivedMessages 

    where ReceivedMessages.ReceivedDateTime >= @FromDate AND ReceivedMessages.ReceivedDateTime <= @ToDate
    Group By ReceivedMessages.IsComplaint




END
```

Comment: It's because you're using the `CASE columnname WHEN columnvalue` form instead of `CASE WHEN expression THEN return WHEN expression THEN return` form of `CASE`.  Just list the value `1` , rather than a complete expression like `IsCompliant=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in this line

```
CASE ReceivedMessages.IsComplaint WHEN ReceivedMessages.IsComplaint=0
```

it should be like this

```
CASE WHEN ReceivedMessages.IsComplaint=0 THEN 'Incomplete'
WHEN ReceivedMessages.IsComplaint=1 THEN 'Complete'
WHEN ReceivedMessages.IsComplaint=-3 THEN 'Inappropriate' END
```

Answer (score 4):

You're combining two different forms of the `CASE` statement.  You can simplify it this way since you're comparing the same expression in each case:

```
CASE ReceivedMessages.IsComplaint
  WHEN 0  THEN 'Incomplete'
  WHEN 1  THEN 'Complete'
  WHEN -3 THEN 'Inappropriate' 
END from ReceivedMessages
```

The alternative would be:

```
CASE
  WHEN ReceivedMessages.IsComplaint=0  THEN 'Incomplete'
  WHEN ReceivedMessages.IsComplaint=1  THEN 'Complete'
  WHEN ReceivedMessages.IsComplaint=-3 THEN 'Inappropriate' 
END
```